# Visual studio equivalent of java System.out

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

What do I use in Visual Studio (C#) to perform the equivalent of Java's `System.out.println( /*stuff*/ )` ?

Does the output from the command show in the Output window in the IDE?

I have a button on a webpage that calls a service which returns a string. I want to see what's in the string and have tried all the variations below and nothing ever shows up in the output. It also doesn't stop on the breakpoint so I can check if there are any results.

```
var service = new OTest.TylerAPI.APIWebServiceSoapClient();
results = service.OdysseyMsgExecution("<Message MessageType='FindCaseByCaseNumber' Source='APIMessage' ReferenceNumber='1' NodeID='1' UserID='1'> <CaseNumber>T4CV0043212010</CaseNumber></Message>", "NMODYSSEYMETRO");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(results);
```

Comment: if it doesn't hit the breakpoint I suspect the code is not executed at all.

Comment: you're right, i put the breakpoint on the first line (var service) and it stops, when i step in i catch the error: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Comment: Yes, code after exception place is not executed. Try posting a new question tagged with web-service and describe as much as possible the problem and exception details, you will attract more answerers.

Answer (score 63):

Try:  [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=VS.100).aspx) (type `out` for a Visual Studio or Rider snippet)

```
Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

Another way is to use [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stuff);
```

`Debug.WriteLine` may suit better for Output window in IDE because it will be rendered for both Console and Windows applications. Whereas `Console.WriteLine` won't be rendered in Output window but only in the Console itself in case of Console Application type.

Another difference is that `Debug.WriteLine` will not print anything in Release configuration.

Comment: Why the latter is better?

Answer (score 6):

Use Either `Debug.WriteLine()` or `Trace.WriteLine()`. If in release mode, only the latter will appear in the output window, in debug mode, both will.

Answer (score 1):

In `System.Diagnostics`,

```
Debug.Write()
Debug.WriteLine()
```

etc. will print to the Output window in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to see output in the Output window of Visual Studio, [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stuff)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Console.WriteLine()` to write out any native type. To see the output you must write console application (like in Java), then the output will be displayed in the Command Prompt, or if you are developing a windows GUI application, in Visual Studio you must turn on "Output" panel (under View) to see the commands output.